# Django easy-thumbnails: Copy a ThumbnailerImagefield object

Tags: python, django, object, copy, easy-thumbnails

I have this in my models.py:

```
class MyModel(models.Model)
    imgA = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to="site_images/",
                                 null=True, blank=True)
    imgB = ThumbnailerImageField(upload_to="site_images/",
                                 null=True, blank=True)
```

and I want to copy imgA to imgB so I tried:

```
def copy_thumbnailer():
    obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
    obj.imgB = obj.imgA
    obj.save()
```

The function run with no errors, but the ThumbnailerImageField it's not copied. There's some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:** You must use get_thumbnailer() method. Here we go:

```
from easy_thumbnails.files import get_thumbnailer
def copy_thumbnailer():
    obj = MyModel.objects.get(id=1)
    obj.imgB = get_thumbnailer(obj.imgA)
    obj.save()
```

[More details about get_thumbnailer()](http://easy-thumbnails.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ref/files/#easy_thumbnails.files.Thumbnailer.get_thumbnail)